# Clear difference between spring web and spring web flux

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-webflux

I know this question has been asked a lot but i'm not able to find a CLEAR answer to my question.

The main difference i see between spring web and spring web flux is the use of Mono and Flux and ReactiveRepository. My question is : What is the difference ? (other than a syntax difference). I assume everything is different in the background but do we see these differences? Can we make something with flux that we cannot make with web mvc ?

I made a simple spring boot application using flux (playing with mono and flux) but only the syntax change, for me, i don't see any differences.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Spring Reactive](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web-reactive.html) Gives the overview of WebFlux and Webflux is for asynchronous reactive programming & implements the [Reactive Stream specification](https://github.com/reactive-streams/reactive-streams-jvm/blob/v1.0.3/README.md) and webflux is for NIO uses cases.